# Xcode 8 Swift 3 missing "Main Interface"

Tags: xcode8

I have been working on a project in Beta Xcode 8 using Swift 3 and just today when I tried to build my application I found that the "Main Interface" in Targets is missing and when I try to drop down to choose nothing is there.

Checked my storyboards and they are added to the project.  Checked my storyboards for entry points, those exist and are in the right place.

The project builds to a black screen.  Tried removing and re-adding entry points and that did not work.

If I try to force the name of the storyboard into the Main Interface I get errors saying that storyboard does not exist, it does and it is in the project.

Wondering if anyone came across this project and has a solution.

Comment: This is what I have found out...  I removed the reference to the storyboards and then re-added them to the project.  I can now choose them.  Still not sure how this happened...

Comment: It doesn't sound familiar, but can you please attach your sample project at bugreport.apple.com so we can investigate?

Comment: It was just a bug when using the new xcode beta and sharing projects.  I solved this by simply removing the reference to the storyboard and then re-importing them.